# Reload the web page only once in the media query with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I want to reload the page in a certain media query only once, but each time the web page is loaded, the media query is run and the page is reloaded in a loop.

I tried to use the answer to the following question but it did not help and this problem still exists.
[stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408927/refresh-the-page-once-when-media-query-is-triggered)

My Codes

```
tablet();
function tablet(){
    const mql = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991px)');
    checkMedia(mql);
    mql.addListener(checkMedia);
    function checkMedia(mql){
        if(mql.matches){
            console.log('tablet');
          
          //   location.reload();
          location.href = window.location.href + "?tablet=1";}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to solve your problem.

You can store a value in `localStorage` before reloading the page. And each time when you are going to reload the page, just check if the variable exists in the `localStorage` or not:

```
function checkMedia(mql){
        // Check here if there is a value exists in the localStorage
        if(mql.matches && !localStorage.getItem("your_variable")){
            console.log('tablet');
          
          //   location.reload();
         // Before reload, store a variable in localStorage
         localStorage.setItem("your_variable", true);
          location.href = window.location.href + "?tablet=1";}}}
```